# Function bijection question

Tags: functions

a)  Let S be the set { n ∈ N | 0 ≤ n ≤ 11 } and define f : S → S by letting f(n) be the remainder when 5n + 2 is divided by 12.

```
i.  Is f one-to-one? 
ii. Is f onto?
```

b)  Repeat part (a) with 5n + 2 replaced by 4n + 2.

these are the question. So im confused as to what is the function and i dont even know how to start working on this.

Comment: Do you know about the mod operator?

Comment: That's the whole question that i got. What is a mod operator?

Comment: The function is the remainder when $5n+2$ is divided by $12$. So for example, when $n = 3$, then $5n+2 = 17$. the remainder when it is divided by $12$ is $5$, so $f(3) = 5$. When $n=2$, we have $f(2) = 0$, and so on.

Comment: @Camille omg thank you so much. The remainder thing is the reason im so confused. So in order to answer the question i just need to insert any number and see if its surjective or injective? Is that right?

Comment: Hmm, not how I would phrase surjectivity and injectivity. But you know what they are, I presume?